# Salesforce Platform Events Pricing

Tags: integration, platform-event

We are implementing a sub/pub pattern in SAlesforce and as I see I am able to create platform events object. So before moving to prod, I want to check if Platform events are free or are there any price attached to it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are free if you have a sufficiently high enough subscription. From the related [help topic](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=platform_events.htm&type=5):

> Available in: Performance, Unlimited, Enterprise, and Developer Editions